# How to set reply-timeout on a socket with spring-integration?

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-integration

I create a `nio` socket server as follows.

How can I define a timeout that will automatically send some kind of error response back to the client, if the timeout is exceeded?

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class SocketEndpoint {
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "serverChannel", sendTimeout = "5000")
    public String handleMessage(String message) {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(60);
        //...TODO how to send some kind of "timeout exceeded" response?
    }
}

    @Bean
    public TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean factory() {
        TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean f = new TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean();
        f.setType("server");
        f.setPort(port);
        f.setUsingNio(true);
        f.setSingleUse(false);
        f.setDeserializer(deserializer);
        f.setSerializer(serializer);
        return f;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpInboundGateway server(
            TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean factory,
            MessageChannel serverChannel) throws Exception {
        TcpInboundGateway g = new TcpInboundGateway();
        g.setConnectionFactory(factory.getObject());
        g.setRequestChannel(serverChannel);
        return g;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that.

On the client side you can set a socket timeout so the client will get an exception if a reply is not received within that time.

Comment: That's exactly what the client system does (a legacy system). But I want to anticipate that timeout and myself generate a proper error message that I can send back to the client before a timeout occurs. (because the legacy systems' timeout procedures are not properly working). I can only think of wrapping my method execution into a `CompletableFuture` and call `future.get(...timeout)` to terminate before client timeout.